# Why is one kind of S3 link slower than the other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Below are download times for 'made public' files downloaded from buckets with different **URL scheme**. The S3 server is at Oregon AZ, US west coast. I am at Kochi, a port city with internet cables in the west coast of India.

Why does `bukkit.s3.amazonaws.com` take much longer vs `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bukkit` which can be as low as 700ms? I would imagine that custom subdomains need extra SSL verification and routing.

So when I am linking to static and public-hosted assets in HTML, should I always use the first scheme as it is generally faster **all over the world**?

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bukkit/image.jpg
[image]

https://bukkit.s3.amazonaws.com/image.jpg
[image]

---

Previous version was from a highly-skewed outlier morning, 2.3s vs 13.44s.

Comment: There shouldn't be so much of difference. How many times did you repeat your tests?

Comment: I agree. 7 seconds for retrieving an object from S3 is much too slow. However, if latency is something that you're trying to fight, it might make sense to wrap a cloudfront distribution around your bucket.

Comment: @TJ- I tried again, the performance has improved and the gap has closed. But the subdomain version is still slower.

Comment: In order to ensure the correctness of your hypothesis, repeat your tests several times in identical environments. Perhaps use a tool like blazemeter.com. I also tend to agree with your hypothesis (barring the value of delta) because I think there would be an extra hop in the latter case. s3.amazonaws does not know in which region does the bucket `bukkit` reside. However, s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com definitely does.

Comment: https://bucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/image.jpg would also be valid... how does that one perform?  There should be no difference in any of these, since bucket.s3... is mapped by s3 to the correct regional endpoint in dns after the bucket is created... requests don't stop in us-east-1 to ask for directions.